When CallAcceptDateTime is populated in VoiceCall record
I need to know when the CallAcceptDateTime on a VoiceCall records is populated in order to create a Case records in that moment. I have written the afterUpdate method in our voicecall trigger but it seems to not be fired.
VoiceCallTrigger
trigger SCV_trg_VoiceCallTrigger on VoiceCall (before insert,before update, after insert) {
    SCV_cls_VoiceCallTriggerHandler voiceHandler = new SCV_cls_VoiceCallTriggerHandler();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            voiceHandler.doBeforeInsert(Trigger.New);
        }else{
            voiceHandler.doAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            voiceHandler.doBeforeUpdate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.New);
        }else{
            voiceHandler.doAfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}

VoiceCallHandler
public void doAfterUpdate(List<VoiceCall> newVoiceCalls, Map<Id, VoiceCall> oldVoiceCallsMap){
        Map<Id, VoiceCall> mapVCOld = new Map<Id, VoiceCall> ([SELECT Id, SCV_fld_case__c, RelatedRecordId, SCV_fld_queue__c, Description, SCV_fld_transfer__c,CallAcceptDateTime FROM VoiceCall WHERE Id IN :oldVoiceCallsMap.keySet()]);
        Map<Id, VoiceCall> mapVCNew = new Map<Id, VoiceCall> ([SELECT Id, SCV_fld_case__c, RelatedRecordId, SCV_fld_queue__c, Description, SCV_fld_transfer__c,CallAcceptDateTime FROM VoiceCall WHERE Id IN :newVoiceCalls]);
        
        for (VoiceCall vc : mapVCOld.values()) {
            System.debug('VoiceCall Id: ' + vc.Id);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_case__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_case__c);
            System.debug('RelatedRecordId: ' + vc.RelatedRecordId);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_queue__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_queue__c);
            System.debug('Description: ' + vc.Description);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_transfer__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_transfer__c);
            System.debug('CallAcceptDateTime: ' + vc.CallAcceptDateTime);
        }

        for (VoiceCall vc : mapVCNew.values()) {
            System.debug('VoiceCall Id: ' + vc.Id);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_case__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_case__c);
            System.debug('RelatedRecordId: ' + vc.RelatedRecordId);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_queue__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_queue__c);
            System.debug('Description: ' + vc.Description);
            System.debug('SCV_fld_transfer__c: ' + vc.SCV_fld_transfer__c);
            System.debug('CallAcceptDateTime: ' + vc.CallAcceptDateTime);
        }
}


Your text mentions afterUpdate, but your code is marked as beforeUpdate.  Please [edit] your post to clarify.
